# How to map Object type in JAXB

Tags: json, object, jaxb, adapter, jackson

Lots of examples are out there for how to map in JAXB using XmlTypeAdapters, and that's great.

However, my situation is I have a field which can by any type (ie: Object.class in Java). What I want is to use an adapter that basically passes all control for marshalling/unmarshalling for that field to me. Again, I don't know the incoming type, nor do I know the outgoing type except at runtime.

For example:

```
@XmlRootElement( name="myType" )
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class MyType {
   @XmlElement("value")
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ValueAdapter.class)
   private Object value;

   public static class ValueAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, Object> {

       public ValueAdapter() {

       }

       public Object marshal(Object value) {
           if (value instanceof Date) {
               // do date stuff
           }
           else if (value instanceof Foo) {
               // do foo stuff
           }
           // ... etc ...
           else {
               return value;
           }
       }

       public Object unmarshal(Object value) {
           if (value instanceof Date) {
               // do date stuff
           }
           else if (value instanceof Foo) {
               // do foo stuff
           }
           // ... etc ...
           else {
               return value;
           }
       }
    }

    // getter/setter fluff ...

}
```

However, using Jackson, ValueAdapter isn't called.

Is this the right way to do this in JAXB? If not, what is the way to do this?

Comment: Gaaah!  +1 dweeb points for me. I wasn't seeing breakpoints being reached in the adapter. After cleaning my project in my IDE, breakpoints are hit as expected and above solutions works. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Glad that it works. Now, since you are using Jackson, there may also be fully automated way.

Specifically for polymorphic types you can often get proper handling by using `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation -- it will add type information when serializing, use that when deserializing. And as long as actual concrete types have handlers (standard JDK types, beans, collections of other handled types), that's all you need.